# is routesegment available in angular2/router?

Tags: angular, typescript

I know angular2 support RouteSegment while importing @angular/router, But i want to use from angular2/router;

import { Component, Input, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import { Router, RouteSegment }     from 'angular2/router';

export class ContentTreeComponent implements OnInit {

```
constructor(
    private _contentService: ContentService,
    private router: Router,
    private _currSegment: RouteSegment
) { }
```

Is it any possible to use? Otherwise what is the right way to do this?

Comment: why do you need it?

Comment: For Using Recursive Tree, Now am Getting error like below                                                                angular2.dev.js:23083 EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ContentTreeComponent'(ContentService, Router, ?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'ContentTreeComponent' is decorated with Injectable.